# Sublime Text: Accept Suggested Autocomplete Without Expanding it

Tags: html, autocomplete, sublimetext, emmet

In Sublime Text, I have installed Emmet so that I can do zen coding.  Now, the problem is that when I'm typing, and get an autocomplete suggestion, as soon as I accept that autocomplete suggestion (either by entering tab, enter, or even pressing space bar), the suggested tag is expanded; this causes me not to be able to continue the zen coding.

To give you an example, say I want to insert a `<select>` with 6 `<option>` child elements. If I enter `select>opt`, then autocomplete suggests `option`, but as soon as I accept `option`, that expands to `select<option></option>`.

What I want is to accept `option`, but that it won't expand to `<option></option>`.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer is very simple.  In your example, when you get the autocomplete suggestions for `option`, you will get 2 of them.  One is the tag, the other is text.  Use Ctrl+Space to go through all the suggestions, and select the text version of `option` and not the tag version.

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text completions consists of a 2-tuple containing the showed string and the inserted characters/snippet. I don't think know whether it is possible to just insert the showed string. However if you search for any way, there is a way to establish: modify the source code of the html tag completion file.

Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer), then press `ctrl+shift+p` write `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`. Select `HTML >>> html_completions.py`.
If you save the file it will shadow (not overwrite) the original completions file. Hence just remove it to get the original behavior.
In this file:

- in line `15` replace `return (tag + '\tTag', tag + '>$0</' + tag)` by `return (tag + '\tTag', tag)`.
- in line `245` replace `completion_list = [(pair[0], '<' + pair[1]) for pair in completion_list]` by `completion_list = [(pair[0], pair[1]) for pair in completion_list]`

Now it should insert the tag names instead of the whole tags.